# How to declare a Slice of Slice of structs without a set len nor capacity in Golang

Tags: go, data-structures, slice

I'm trying to fill **grantJointResponse** with slices of my struct **granJoin**, the data it's coming from a query and the slices can have diferent sizes. This will be easy in languagues like Python or JS, but I have tried a couple of combinations in Golang and can't make it work. I pressume has something to do with the declarations of the Slices, I have tried with **grantJointResponse[contadorOwners] = make(granJoin, 0)**, with **grantJointResponse := [][]granJoin{}**, with **grantJointResponse[contadorOwners] = granJoin{}** and I can' figure it out, most likely it's something easy and I'm not seeing it (I'm kind of new with Golang). This current version get an **index out of range in   grantJointResponse[contadorOwners] = []granJoin{auxJoin}**. So if anyone knows how to do this it will be appreciated :)

```
import (
    "fmt"
    .
    .
    .
    "log"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq" 
    "database/sql"
)

type granJoin struct{
    property_id sql.NullInt64
    owner_id sql.NullInt64
}
```

```
rows, err := dbLeasity.Query(contractsQuery)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
current_owner_id := int64(-1)
contadorOwners := -1
cntProp := 0
var grantJointResponse [][]granJoin
for rows.Next() {
    var auxJoin granJoin
    if err := rows.Scan(&auxJoin.owner_id, &auxJoin.property_id); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if (auxJoin.owner_id.Valid){
        if (current_owner_id == -1){
            grantJointResponse = [][]granJoin{{auxJoin}}
        }
        if (auxJoin.owner_id.Int64 != current_owner_id){
            cntProp = 0
            contadorOwners++
            current_owner_id = auxJoin.owner_id.Int64 
            if (current_owner_id != -1){
                grantJointResponse[contadorOwners] = []granJoin{auxJoin}
            }
        }
        if (cntProp != 0){
            grantJointResponse[contadorOwners] = append(grantJointResponse[contadorOwners], auxJoin)
        }
        cntProp++
    }
}
```

I hope to create something like this :

```
// Data that will be in the rows
granJoin1 = { {true, 1}, {true, 10} }
granJoin2 = { {true, 2}, {true, 11} }
granJoin3 = { {true, 2}, {true, 12} }
granJoin4 = { {true, 2}, {true, 13} }
granJoin5 = { {true, 3}, {true, 14} }
granJoin6 = { {true, 3}, {true, 15} }

//The way I need to be on the Slice of Slices 
grantJointResponse := {
  {granJoin1},
  {granJoin2, granJoin3, granJoin4},
  {granJoin5, granJoin6}
}
```

Comment: Work throug the slice parts of the Tour of Go.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/wwSPiv8UxnF Ignore the `go vet` warnings. And ignore the fact that the code seems to be unnecessarily sorting an already sorted slice (the slice is sorted only by happenstance). In reality the initial result will not be sorted because maps in Go are intentionally unsorted, i.e. looping over an unsorted map and appending its elements to a slice will produce an unsorted slice.

Comment: To create slices without a set length you should just use append. In your code instead of creating a single element slice and appending to it start with a nil slice.  Appending to a nil slice will create the slice, including allocating memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a nil (inner) slice and a nil slice of slices.  As you get new records append to the inner slice.  When the owner ID changes append the inner slice to the the end of the slice of slices and set it to nil to start building another inner slice.

Note that you don't need to keep counts `cntProp` and `contadorOwners` since you just append the slice.  Also, if you start with a `nil` slice you can just append and the underlying array will be allocated for you.  Here is some code that is close to something that may work for you but I have not tested it:

```
rows, err := dbLeasity.Query(contractsQuery)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
current_owner_id := int64(-1)
var grantJointResponse [][]granJoin
var oneSlice []granJoin
for rows.Next() {
    var auxJoin granJoin
    if err := rows.Scan(&auxJoin.owner_id, &auxJoin.property_id); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if (auxJoin.owner_id.Valid){
        if (auxJoin.owner_id.Int64 != current_owner_id){
            if oneSlice != nil {
                grantJointResponse = append(grantJointResponse, oneSlice)
                oneSlice = nil
            }
            current_owner_id = auxJoin.owner_id.Int64
        }
        oneSlice = append(oneSlice, auxJoin)
    }
}
if oneSlice != nil {
    grantJointResponse = append(grantJointResponse, oneSlice)
}
```